# Problem with get single value from db mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've a problem with get a single value from mysql and variable assignment. 
`var_dump($val)` looks ok:

> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["min(ID_plants)"]=> string(1) "1" }

And i need this "1" assign to variable.

```php
$first= "SELECT min(ID_plants) from Plants";
if (mysqli_query($link,$first)){
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$first);
    $val = mysqli_fetch_object($res);
}
//var_dump($val);
//$first_index$=($val->MIN(ID_plants));
```

Comment: use alias to fetch min(ID_plants), that would might help. Like this 
$first= "SELECT min(ID_plants) as minid from Plants";
/**
rest of the code 
*/
$first_index = $val->minid;
echo $first_index;

Answer (score 2):

you should use an alias for min(ID_plants)

```
$first= "SELECT min(ID_plants) my_min_id from Plants";
 if (mysqli_query($link,$first)){
     $res = mysqli_query($link,$first);
     $val = mysqli_fetch_object($res);
 }
 //var_dump($val);
 $first_index$=($val->my_min_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prepared statement` instead of `mysqli`.

Change your query to

```
 SELECT min(ID_plants) As minPlants from Plants // Alias
```

After `$val = mysqli_fetch_object($res);` you can get the value by using `$val->minPlants`